# MVC4 async await has any benefit if we only have series of calls with no independent work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a MVC application.I have situation like this-- I need to bring data from multiple APIs.

```
public class MVCController : Controller
{
    // MVC controller calling WebApis to bring data.
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var response1 = await client.GetAsync("webapi/WebApiController1/Method1");
        var response2 = await client.GetAsync("webapi/WebApiController2/Method2");
        var response3 = await client.GetAsync("webapi/WebApiController3/Method3");
        var response4 = await client.GetAsync("webapi/WebApiController4/Method4");
    }
}
```

I feel since every call to the webApi has await, it is not giving me any benefit. Since anyhow we will have to wait for data to come before we proceed with the next call. For example 1st call will have to wait until it gets back the response1 and so on. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Is there any way i can execute these 4 statements in parallel since any of these do not have dependency and if i can finally put await at bottom before passing the model to the view?

If there is any approach to do that without risking of passing incomplete/partial data to the View and getting the data from these Web API calls in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way i can execute these 4 statements in parallel

Yes, it's called [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var response1 = client.GetAsync("webapi/WebApiController1/Method1");
    var response2 = client.GetAsync("webapi/WebApiController2/Method2");
    var response3 = client.GetAsync("webapi/WebApiController3/Method3");
    var response4 = client.GetAsync("webapi/WebApiController4/Method4");

    await Task.WhenAll(response1, response2, response3, response4);
    // You will reach this line once all requests finish execution.
}
```

This way you concurrently execute 4 tasks and wait for them to complete. The method will continue execution once they all finished receiving the requests.

Comment: ok. Earlier with the code of my problem statement:
var response1 = await client.GetAsync("webapi/LiveListing/topLiveListings")

Since return of response1 is HttpResponseMessage, i was able to access properties like: response1.IsSuccessStatusCode, response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

But now with modified code:
 var response1 =  client.GetAsync("webapi/LiveListing/topLiveListings");

The return of this response1 is Task<HttpResponseMessage> so i can't access those properties. Its a compile time error.

Comment: @sahil I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: @sahil I have upvoted this answer, I just want to note for the author of the question that creating multiple requests won't have to be here n-cores faster, they all go through one cable in the end, but it can cut costs on server with initializations and some processings of the data...

Comment: I have posted the full comment now. Previous one was by mistake.

Comment: @ipavlu This has nothing to do with cores. This is async IO. It only depends on the bandwidth his server has with the said WebAPI.

Comment: @sahil You know have to do `response1.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode` instead. Or, you can do `var actualResponse = await response1; actualResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode`. `await` is optimized for completed task scenarios and will only unwrap the value.

Comment: @Yuval- I have two choices now. I can use this method or call repositories/database layer directly for these. As we do with normal synchronous approach. Taking data from database one by one for every resource. Do you think this would be significantly fast? I am unable to see it by first few results?

Comment: @Yuval: It would be great if you can tell how we should handle the situation of deadlock here. For example one api not returning any data. How to put timeout etc.?

Comment: @sahil If you're using `HttpClient`, it has a `TimeOut` you can pass each of its method, look into it. Regarding that database, I don't know, that will really depend on what queries you're doing and how they split between tables. You'll have to test and see.

Comment: @Yuval: How do i read this response?"
var response1 = await client.GetAsync("webapi/LiveListing/topLiveListings");
OR
response1.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ToString() [This is giving me runtime exception].

But why should i use await? Can you please suggest to read this?

Comment: @Yuval: I see pretty strange results. I have made 2 controllers-one sync and other async. Sync is calling repositories to fetch same database table data 10 times. While AsyncController is calling Web Api 10 times asyncronously and the api  fetches the data from same tables.

But i do not see any difference in the page load time?

Comment: @sahil You won't see any difference with 10 requests at a time. Perhaps you'll even see async perform worse in such scenarios. Async will shine when you need to handle heavy traffic, which isn't simulated with 10 requests.

Comment: Well, it always depends on cores but with different kind results:). On one core, there could be just one attempt to call GetAsync in given time, on four cores, there could be four in the same time. As I stated in my first comment, it gets through one cable, though so in then end it will synchronize itself in some lock deep down in the TCP stack of the OS and small benefit is that the methods data structures can be created/initiated concurrently, but sure, it is all lost with waiting on TCP packets of shared pipe.

Comment: @ipavlu I'm not sure why you say that. A single core can schedule multiple overlapped IRP. The core does not wait for the completion of each request, so they will be scheduled concurrently, even on a single core.